# Cannot resolve firebasedatabase given I have added the dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have added the required dependencies but even then when I write the code it cannot resolve firebasedatabase

build gradle module app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kiit.questionme2"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think I have added the required dependencies but my system cannot resolve firebasedatabase How do I do it? I have been stuck here for quite a while now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Realtime Database , Cloud Firestore will be advantageous if you are implementing Analytics try this :

```
 >com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5
```

Comment: How to use it? I am new to this

Comment: Just like realtime database there are various functions in cloud firestore which helps for writing efficient queries as it has  more intuitive data model also you can implement cloud functions very efficiently with cloud firstore.This link will help you to implement cloud firestore for your project : >https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore